# Difference between .split(/\s+/) and .split(" ")?

Tags: javascript, regex

:) First of all, sorry my bady english :p
I was taking a look to the next js code fragment:

```
var classes = element.className.split(/\s+/);
```

That code will split the full classname of and element into an array containing every class... but, what's the difference between using `.split(/\s+/)`, and using `.split(" ")`? i see the same result...

I tested this with the next simple code in Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="cono" class="clase1 clase2 clase3-xD">
    </div>
    <script>
        var d = document.getElementById("cono");
        console.log(d.className);
        var classes = d.className.split(" ");
        for (i in classes) {
            console.log(classes[i]);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the same result whether i use `.split(" ")` or `.split(/\s+/)`:

> clase1 clase2 clase3-xD
>
> clase1
>
> clase2
>
> clase3-xD

Do they have any relevant difference?

Comment: `\s` captures more whitespace than just the space character

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The difference between .split(" ") and .split(/\s+/) is:

The regex `" "`

- Match the space character literally.

The regex `/\s+/`

- Match a single whitespacecharacter (tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed) between one and unlimmited times. (greedy)

---

Short:

`" "`   splits the array at one single space character.
`/\s/` splits the array at every kind of whitespace character
`+`      Matches between one and unlimitted times

Comment: Thank you lol, you are my lifesaver for my project

Answer (score 13):

No, `.split(/\s+/)`, and  `.split(" ")` are different ones. `\s+` matches one or more space characters including line breaks where `" "` matches a single horizontal space character. So `.split(/\s+/)` splits the input according to one or more space characters and `.split(" ")` splits the input according to a single space.

Example:

```
> "foo   bar".split(/\s+/)
[ 'foo', 'bar' ]
> "foo   bar".split(" ")
[ 'foo', '', '', 'bar' ]
```

Comment: @Antony Sottile too

Ohhh i get it... so \s+ will work fine even if the classes of the element were separated by more than one space...

Thanks! :)

Comment: Ye but he answer the question too... so my thanks are for you and him ahah

Comment: @Justme [accept an answer which helps you the most..](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 2):

`\s` captures more types of whitespace than space

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions:

Matches a single white space character, including space, tab, form feed, line feed. Equivalent to `[ \f\n\r\t\v​\u00a0\u1680​\u180e\u2000​\u2001\u2002​\u2003\u2004​\u2005\u2006​\u2007\u2008​\u2009\u200a​\u2028\u2029​​\u202f\u205f​\u3000]`.

Also the `+` means it will match on multiple spaces.  So `foo       bar` will produce a different result:

```
js> 'foo      bar'.split(' ')
["foo", "", "", "", "", "", "bar"]
js> 'foo      bar'.split(/\s+/)
["foo", "bar"]
```