# CSS; inline-flex removing white-space. How to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, css

I am running a simple script that wraps words (and ignores existing HTML markup) inside elements with a specific class in span tags.

Here's said script;

```
$('.has-transition_text-reveal').each(function() {
    $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).replaceWith(function() {
        return this.nodeValue.split(/(?=\b\s)/).map(str => `<span class="text-reveal_wrapper"><span class="text-reveal">${str}</span></span>`)
    });
});
```

Here's some example markup;

```
<h1><small class="has-transition_text-reveal">Test <span class="text-reveal_wrapper"><span class="text-reveal"><span> test-test<sup><ion-icon name="cloudy-outline"></ion-icon></sup></span></span></span> test test & test test — test test test, <span class="text-reveal_wrapper"><span class="text-reveal"><span>test test<sup><ion-icon name="chatbubbles-outline"></ion-icon></sup></span></span></span>.</small></h1>
```

And here's the CSS that's causing the white-space to be removed;

```
.text-reveal_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-reveal {
  // transform: translateY(100%);
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

Does anyone know of a way around this dilemma?

P.S. Adding white-space break-spaces, pre or pre-wrap doesn't fix the issue entirely as it leaves whitespaces at the beginning of new lines in some cases.

```js
$('.has-transition_text-reveal').each(function() {
  $(this).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  }).replaceWith(function() {
    return this.nodeValue.split(/(?=\b\s)/).map(str => `<span class="text-reveal_wrapper"><span class="text-reveal">${str}</span></span>`)
  });
});
```

```css
.text-reveal_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-reveal {
  // transform: translateY(100%);
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1><small class="has-transition_text-reveal">Test <span class="text-reveal_wrapper"><span class="text-reveal"><span> test-test<sup><ion-icon name="cloudy-outline"></ion-icon></sup></span></span></span> test test & test test — test test test, <span class="text-reveal_wrapper"><span class="text-reveal"><span>test test<sup><ion-icon name="chatbubbles-outline"></ion-icon></sup></span></span></span>.</small></h1>
```

Comment: Does `white-space: pre;` solve it?

Comment: Sorry, just edited the q to include this. It leaves whitespaces at the start of new lines in some cases unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way to be selective about which whitespace it replaces and which it leaves alone.

Comment: You could replace the spaces that you want to keep with `&nbsp;`

Comment: That could work. Or if the white-spaces themselves are wrapped in the spans. I am unsure how to update my code for either of these tbh though, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `.split(/(?=\b\s)/)` regex doesn't consider `&` char.

You can change it to `.split(/\s+/)`:

```js
$('.has-transition_text-reveal').each(function() {
  $(this).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  }).replaceWith(function() {
    return this.nodeValue
      .split(/\s+/)
      .map(str => {
        return `<span class="text-reveal_wrapper">
        <span class="text-reveal">${str}</span>
        </span>`
      })
  });
});
```

```css
.text-reveal_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-reveal {
  // transform: translateY(100%);
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script 
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<h1>
  <small class="has-transition_text-reveal">
    Test 
    <span class="text-reveal_wrapper">
      <span class="text-reveal">
        <span>
          test-test
          <sup>
            <ion-icon name="cloudy-outline"></ion-icon>
          </sup>
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
    test test & test test — test test test, 
    <span class="text-reveal_wrapper">
      <span class="text-reveal">
        <span>
          test test
          <sup>
            <ion-icon name="chatbubbles-outline"></ion-icon>
          </sup>
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
    .
  </small>
</h1>
```

##### Reference:

[Difference between .split(/\s+/) and .split(" ")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127794/difference-between-split-s-and-split)

Comment: I think maybe you misunderstood me - granted, perhaps I didn't explain well. I need the white-space to remain, and need a way to prevent it from collapsing. Maybe if the white-spaces themselves are wrapped in the span's, that could work?